# Оптимизация запросов SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли оптимизировать как-то следующие строки

```
DECLARE @active bit = (SELECT Active FROM People)
DECLARE @name nvarchar(50) = (SELECT Name FROM People)
DECLARE @age int = (SELECT Age FROM People)
```

Просто немного напрягает, что три переменные я получаю тремя запросами к одной таблице.
Можно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Заранее спасибо.

MSSQL (хотя без разницы, напишите под любую СУБД ответ)

Comment: У Вас что, одна запись в таблице? по идее СУБД должна послать в даль туманную, предполагая, что вернётся набор записей, который не влезет в скалярную переменную...

Comment: Да, была одна запись, по-хорошему надо указать where что-то там откуда-то там. Но мне сама идея нужна была. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена

```
DECLARE @active bit, @name nvarchar(50);
select @active = Active, @name = Name  from people;
```